# Getting phantom 'b' when converting numpy object array to datetime

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, datetime, object

I have a large data set with many columns. I am making each column an array. The first column is time in `$H:$M:$S`

```
00:00:00
00:00:01
00:00:02
...
23:59:58
23:59:59
```

When I put this into an array, it makes an object array. I use this to convert it to datetime:

```
time1=np.array2string(time)                  
dt.datetime.strptime(time1, "%H:%M:%S")
```

However, I keep getting an error:

```
ValueError: time data "[b'00:00:00' b'00:01:00' b'00:02:00' ... b'23:57:00' b'23:58:00'\n b'23:59:00']" does not match format '%H:%M:%S'
```

When I look at the actual array, it indeed does have that phantom 'b', but there is no 'b' in my dataset. It generates it out of thin air. What is causing this?

UPDATE:

I tried

```
time1=np.array2string(time)                  
time_strings = [dt.datetime.strptime(t, "%H:%M:%S") for t in time1]
```

and received the error:

```
ValueError: time data '[' does not match format '%H:%M:%S'
```

Not sure why a bracket is in there. It still appears to be making a 'b'.

Comment: `strptime` takes a string as first positional argument, not the string representation of a whole array (which is what you tried to do). could use list comp instead: `time_strings = [dt.datetime.strptime(t, "%H:%M:%S") for t in time]`

Comment: prefix `b` indicates binary strings. maybe your data is encoded as binary?

Comment: @QuangHoang: have a look at the return value of `np.array2string` - it will be hard to make `datetime.datetime.strptime` work with that I guess

Comment: @MrFuppes didn't notice the function. No idea why OP used it anyway.

Comment: I am still receiving errors and edited the question to show them. The "type" of object array for time is listed as "bytes64".

Comment: I did that too. Using just your line of code I got error ```TypeError: strptime() argument 1 must be str, not numpy.bytes_```.

Comment: ok let's start over: how does `time` look like in the first place, what is its `dtype`?

Comment: Type is bytes64

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your input seems to be an array of byte objects. you'll need to decode the bytes to string before you can parse them with `strptime`.
example:

```
from datetime import datetime
import numpy as np

time = np.array([b'00:00:00', b'00:00:01', b'00:00:02'])

dt_list = [datetime.strptime(t.decode(encoding='utf-8'), "%H:%M:%S") for t in time]

# dt_list 
# [datetime.datetime(1900, 1, 1, 0, 0),
#  datetime.datetime(1900, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1),
#  datetime.datetime(1900, 1, 1, 0, 0, 2)]
```

note: 'utf-8' is the default, adjust if you have a different encoding.

Comment: sidenote: this seems like a pretty inefficient way to store something with 8 bytes per entry that only needs max. 3 bytes :)